# Communicating between a windows and linux docker container on the same host

Tags: docker

This may seem trivial, but after some trial error I come to the SO community for a little help!

I create a network, call it docker-net.

I have a linux container, let's all it LC1, that has a published port of 6789 (so when created it had the parameter -p 6789:6789) and I make it join docker-net network (--network docker-net)
This works fine, through my host, I can communicate with it no problem.

I switch to the windows containers and check that LC1 is still running. It does! Amazing.

I create a container, let's call it WC1. It also publishes a port of 9000 that maps internally to 80 (-p 9000:80)

The application inside WC1 tries to connect to LC1 using the IP assigned from the network (docker inspect LC1) and I can't communicate.

There's probably a concept that I can't get my head around to.

I understand that the WC1 and LC1 have different gateways and subnets. Could that be the culprit?

Any help to get me to make that work is appreciated !

**EDIT:**
Here are the commands I ran for the scenario above:

```
docker network create docker-net
docker run -d -p 6789:6789 --name LC1 --network docker-net LC1
docker inspect LC1
```

The IP is 172.18.0.2

switch to the windows container

```
docker run -d -p 9000:80 --name WC1 WC1
```

Comment: Can you please post the commands that you are using to run the containers and their IP addresses?

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: What is the IP address of the WC1? Make sure that they are both up and running. What is the output of: `docker network inspect docker-net`?

Comment: docker network ls in windows containers and linux containers don't have the same data. docker-net is NOT in the windows containers

Comment: Please add some more information about your setup because it is a bit... confusing :) You have one host but what os? What do you mean when you say "switch to the windows containers"?

Comment: :-) Windows 10 Pro OS, switch to the windows containers = go to the whale icon in the task icon bar, right click and do switch to windows containers

Basically, I have an image in linux that is running in a container (linux containers) and I also have a windows image that is running in a container (on the windows containers) and I want the windows image that is running in the container to talk to the linux image in the container in the linux containers?

are you following me?

Answer (score 0):

In the [docker network connect documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/#examples) it states that you can assign an IP to a container the same should work with docker run --network name --ip. Then use that IP to access the container.

> **Specify the IP address a container will use on a given network**
>
> You can specify the IP address you want to be assigned to the
>   container’s interface.
>
> $ docker network connect --ip 10.10.36.122 multi-host-network
>   container2

Comment: like I replied above, docker network ls in windows and linux containers do not have the same data. docker-net is not in the list of networks seen by the windows containers

Answer (score 0):

I have found these:

- a deleted question on serverfault about the same issue. See the cached-by-google version: [Connect Windows container to Linux container running on same Docker host [closed]](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Q91EstQR_4sJ:https://serverfault.com/questions/844480/connect-windows-container-to-linux-container-running-on-same-docker-host+&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=gr&client=firefox-b-ab)
- an article: [Run Linux and Windows Containers on Windows 10](https://stefanscherer.github.io/run-linux-and-windows-containers-on-windows-10/)

and I think that the only way to make the 2 containers communicate is through the host and by exposing ports. For exampple LC1 will use `-p [your app port]:8080` and WC1 `-p [your app port]:9090`.

By saying `[your app port]` I mean that it is up to you to decide what to use (a tcp/udp listening socket, a REST api...)

As docker evolves maybe there will be a better solution in the near future.

Comment: I tried that before posting ;-). It does not work unfortunately. Having the host communicate through the 2 containers that is. I am coming to realisation that the isolation level of the windows vs linux containers does not allow this on the same host. Either you should pick to Docker in linux containers only or to docker in windows containers only, not both